# $K$ convex, with $0\in K$. $\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\Rightarrow\lambda_1 K\subseteq \lambda_2K_2$?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I'm studying a proof in convex analysis, but I don't understand a passage.

I consider $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a convex set such that $0\in K$.

Is it true that $$\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2 \Rightarrow \lambda_1 K\subseteq \lambda_2K_2?$$

I think that the answer is yes, but I don't know how can I use the definition of convex set here. Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean $\lambda_1 K\subseteq \lambda_2 K$.
The typical element of $\lambda_1 K$ is $\lambda_1 a$ with $a\in K$.
This will be in $\lambda_2 K$ iff $\lambda_2^{-1}\lambda_1 a\in K$.
I am presuming that $0<\lambda_1\le\lambda_2$. Then if $t=\lambda_1/\lambda_2$, $0\le t\le1$. Now why should $ta\in K$ whenever $a\in K$?